# Setup a complicated row test with nunit and TestCaseSource and TestCaseData

Tags: nunit, testcasesource, testcasedata

For every expect return value like 2 or 4 I want to pass this value as parameter for the unit test method. But I get an exception that the parameters are not correct. When I remove the countExpected parameter the unit test runs fine I just can not assert the countExpected...

Is this scenario possible at all with NUnit?

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("VisibleWeekDays")]
public void Test(DayOfWeek[] visibleWeekDaysSetup, int countExpected)
{
    // ARRANGE

    // ACT

    // ASSERT
    Assert.That(periods.Count(),Is.EqualTo(countExpected));
}

private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> VisibleWeekDays
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DayOfWeek[] {DayOfWeek.Sunday}).Returns(2);
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DayOfWeek[] {DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Monday}).Returns(4);
        // more days...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See explanation [here](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5):

> **.Returns**
>        The expected result to be returned from the method, which must have a compatible return type.

So, if you want to use `TestCaseData.Returns()`, you need to write test as the following:

```C#
[Test, TestCaseSource("VisibleWeekDays")]
public int Test(DayOfWeek[] visibleWeekDaysSetup)
{
     // ARRANGE

    // ACT

    // ASSERT
    return periods.Count();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to pass expected value as a parameter, you need to pass it as regular test case data. See example:

```C#
[Test, TestCaseSource("VisibleWeekDays")]
public void Test(DayOfWeek[] visibleWeekDaysSetup, int countExpected)
{
    ...

    Assert.That(periods.Count(),Is.EqualTo(countExpected));
}

private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> VisibleWeekDays
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DayOfWeek[] {DayOfWeek.Sunday}, 2);
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DayOfWeek[] {DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Monday}, 4);
        // more days...
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, that looks very unusual. I do not understand, why my expectedCount can not be returned as a method parameter. Whould be much easier to read/understand.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Another example is provided, which shows how to pass expected value as a parameter.